# Why testNG skipping my test?

Tags: java, testing

Here is the code:

```
@DataProvider(name = "DataSource")
public String dataProvider() {

    String name = "ramesh";

    return name;
}

@Test(dataProvider="DataSource")
public void wikiTest(String name) {

    System.out.println(name);

}
```

I am getting the output as

> SKIPPED: wikiTest

can any one help me with this?

Comment: Can you post the complete test case class ?

Comment: Also, how are you running the test suite?

Comment: Guys, I think the issue was DataProvider should return array of array of objects..Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure but DataProvider have to return Object[][] or Iterator.

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders

```
@DataProvider(name = "DataSource")
public Object[][] dataProvider() {
    return new Object[][]{
      {"ramesh"}
    };
}
```

Comment: Oops..I did not read the documentation completely..Now it is working..Thanks for your time.